# Jira create issue returns 405 python

Tags: jira, python-jira

I am using python Jira package and trying to create Jira issue:

```
from jira import JIRA
jiraOptions = {'server': "http://jira.xxx.com"}
jira = JIRA(options = jiraOptions, basic_auth=(
    "xxx", "xxx"))

def create_new_issue(project, summary, description, issuetype, username):
    issue_dict = {
        'project': {'key': project},
        'summary': summary,
        'description': description,
        'issuetype': {'name': issuetype},
        'reporter': {'name': username}
    }
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)

create_new_issue("p1", "test", "teseset", "Bug", "xxxx")
```

I get 405 error which I can't figure out where I got wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\jiraUtil.py", line 97, in <module>
    create_new_issue("p1", "test", "teseset", "Bug", "xxxx")
  File ".\jiraUtil.py", line 58, in create_new_issue
    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 1473, in create_issue
    r = self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 198, in post
    return self.__verb("POST", str(url), data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 189, in __verb
    raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\jira\resilientsession.py", line 64, in raise_on_error
    raise JIRAError(
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 405 url: https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/issue
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, "xxxx" user doesn't exist in your Jira Cloud instance, try changing it to "-1" which is unassigned.
I ran into some issues myself doing this, so I built this project - https://github.com/dren79/JiraScripting_public let me know if it helps :)